# Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::join(), qualify as such or use & at

Tags: perl, perl-core

I have got the error:

```
Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::join(), qualify as such or use & at
```

When I fix error as:

```
$args =  CORE::join( ', ', @$args );
```

everything works fine.

But when I fix it as:

```
$args =  &join( ', ', @$args );
```

As suggested by error message, I got different error:

```
Can't locate object method "_make_instance" via package ", " (perhaps you forgot to load ", "?) at
```

why second fix does not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error because you have a sub named join, so you need to disambiguate it.  To make it call the built-in, prepend `CORE::`.  To make it call the sub, prepend `&`.

The error is because you are calling the sub and **it is actually a method that is expecting an object or class as the first parameter**, which would happen implicitly when you use the method call syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You're getting that warning because you've defined a subroutine called `join`. Now Perl isn't sure whether `join( ', ', @$args )` is supposed to call the built-in function or your subroutine.

`CORE::join` unambiguously calls the built-in [`join`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/join).

`&join(...)` unambiguously calls your subroutine (and overrides any prototype it may have). As for why your subroutine throws bizarre errors about a package called `,` and `_make_instance`, we can't answer that if you don't show us the code.

Comment: `main::join()` (or whatever namespace we happen to be in the scope of) unambiguously calls the subroutine without overriding the prototype. But the best way is to find a better name.